# Error while connecting Azure IoT to Raspberry Pi

Tags: azure, debian

I am trying to install some packages on the raspberry pi  following this guide here: https://indeema.com/blog/connecting-raspberry-pi-via-azure-iot--step-by-step-tutorial but it gives me this error:

```
 dpkg-deb: error: './iotedge.deb' is not a Debian format archive 
 dpkg:error processing archive ./libiothsm-std.deb (--install): 
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
 Errors were encountered while processing: ./libiothsm-std.deb
```

Comment: The link https://aka.ms/libiothsm-std-linux-armhf-latest is broken. It redirects to bing.com and that is exactly what you are downloading. `cat libiothsm-std.deb`. You will see what I mean.

Comment: How do i fix it then?

Comment: This seems to be the release page of the package that you are looking for: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iotedge/releases